# Pyodbc not detecting parameter marker in SQL statement (i.e. - Insert into table SELECT ...) to Hive table. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, pyodbc, impala

My goal is to iterate through a set of values and use them to run a set of queries that will insert their results into a **hive table** using pyodbc.

I tried

```
params = ['USA','JP']
set(params)

for i in params:
    cursor.execute(insert into table **some_db.some_tbl** SELECT name, country from **some_db.some_tbl_2** where country = ?,i)
```

And got the error

> the following and received the error message, ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000').

If I remove the **insert into table some_db.some_tbl** portion, it works fine. Not sure what else to do as all documentation and looking at similar questions suggest what I am doing is correct.

If I keep the **insert into table some_db.some_tbl** portion but remove the parameterization, it works fine.

Comment: how many colums do you habe in some_db.some_tbl ? can you issue like this `cursor.execute(insert into some_db.some_tbl(name, country ) SELECT name, country where country = ?,i)`

Comment: some_db.some_tbl has two columns. I am trying to use a variation of CTAS, ITAS (i.e. - Insert table as select). This actually works if I leave out the parameterization OR the insert, and just use a select. So it seems that both techniques are supported but when combined, I get the error in the original question.

Comment: I've tried your suggested method but the same error is returned. For some reason, the parameter marker is not being recognized when I use "insert into".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this question with a simple workaround as it might help save someone else some time.

Since the **'insert without parameterization'** and a **'select with parameterization'** work independently, I worked around this issue by looping through my parameters with a select statement and then saving the results to a pandas dataframe. From there, you can then run the insert against the pandas dataframe without parameterization for the current iteration. All of this would be in the body of the loop thus accounting for all parameter values separately.